# Eucalyptus can't find ssl certs

Tags: centos6, cloud, eucalyptus

I've installed eucalyptus-cloud, -cc, -sc, -walrus on a single computer to test it, with the intent to install node controllers on my other servers.

When I start eucalyptus-nc it outputs

```
Cannot find keys (node-pk.pem, node-cert.pem) in //var/lib/eucalyptus/keys
```

but otherwise successfully starts

When I run euca_conf --list-nodes it also outputs

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '//var/lib/eucalyptus/keys/cloud-pk.pem'
```

/var/lib/eucalyptus/keys is empty

I'm running CentOS 6.6, eucalyptus 4.0, and I'm hesitant to just generate my own self-signed permissions and copy them in there, because I'm not sure what exactly they're for. I haven't found any references to this in the docs, nor from googling.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: the output when attempting to register nodes is similar (where 192.168.101.1 is the single server running all eucalyptus services)

```
> euca_conf --register-nodes "192.168.101.1"
The following expected credentials are missing:
    /var/lib/eucalyptus/keys/node-cert.pem
    /var/lib/eucalyptus/keys/cluster-cert.pem
    /var/lib/eucalyptus/keys/cloud-cert.pem
    /var/lib/eucalyptus/keys/node-pk.pem
    /var/lib/eucalyptus/keys/cluster-pk.pem
```

Comment: I think you are missing this installation step: https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/4.0.2/index.html#install-guide/registering_ncs.html

Comment: The output is similar, and complains about missing cert files. I added  it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just as I feared.

```
euca_conf --initialize
```

will generate the initial cert files, and registering the other services should generate the rest

Answer (score 0):

When you start eucalyptus-nc for the first time, the "Cannot find keys" is a warning, not an error. It's meant to be informational, in case you did something such as successfully set up the NC for this cloud already, and happened to be restarting. If you know for a fact that this NC is in fact already successfully registered and was working in the past, then that particular warning would be a heads-up as to a possible/likely problem trying to make it work. Meaning, someone may have gone behind your back and removed those key files. In your specific case, being that it's a new install, it's nothing to worry about.

When you ran "euca_conf --list-nodes", did you do so on the CLC?

Comment: This was on a fresh install. It wasn't just saying "Cannot find keys", it was refusing to register anything.